# Group specific column based on another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data that looks like this:

```
extension          directory       size
sql               c:\foo                  2
sql               c:\foo                  3
txt               c:\foo                  5
txt               c:\bar                 .5
txt                c:\bar                 2
xsd               c:\newFoo               4
```

What I need is:

```
extension          directory       size               qty files
sql               c:\foo                  5            2
txt               c:\foo                  5            1
txt               c:\bar                 2.5            2  
xsd              c:\newFoo               4              1
```

I have tried something like

```
SELECT extension, directory, sum(size)
From dbo.Table
Group By extension, directory
```

This rolls all directories up to one not giving me the distinct different values per directory.  Also, I cannot figure out how to get the qty of files "rolled" up.  Can someone offer some assistance?

Comment: `SELECT...count(*) as [qty files]`

Comment: *This rolls all directories up to one not giving me the distinct different values per directory*: But isn't that exactly what you need?

Comment: no @sstan I want all the similar extensions rolled up per dir giving me a line item per unique extension in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT extension, directory, sum(size) as size, count(*) as qty
From dbo.Table
Group By extension, directory;
```

This is a pretty basic aggregation query.  If you could come up with the query in the question, I would expect this to be obvious.

Comment: How did you come up with `avg()` (vs `sum()`)?

Comment: This was a very stupid question I asked.  Thanks for the answer.  Funny thing is the query in my original question actually did work.  How can I close this question down as to not clutter this forum up with junk?

Comment: @PM77-1 . . . Actually, I saw the 2.5 but missed the .5, so figured `avg()` was the intention.